# AttributeError: 'Example' object has no attribute 'Insult' when build vocab using build_vocab() from torchtext

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, spacy, torchtext

I tried to build vocabulary using **.build_vocab()** from **torchtext** in colab. It returns the error message: *AttributeError: 'Example' object has no attribute 'Insult'*

My question is similar to [@szymix12 s question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55060888/torchtext-attributeerror-example-object-has-no-attribute-text-content). His answer is to make sure the order of the fields passed is the same as the csv headers. I confirm that the order I assign is correct. The csv data got two columns:"Insult" (LABEL) and "Comment"(TEXT). "Insult" is a binary label indicator (0 or 1).

The code is as below, I have also made a [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1fCyO3ZAHnObNr4_vm_dVuEksuUbs6UfF). Feel free to run.

```
import os
import torch
from torchtext import data, datasets
from torchtext.utils import download_from_url

CSV_FILENAME = 'data.csv'
CSV_GDRIVE_URL = 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ctPKO-_sJbmc8RodpBZ5-3EyYBWlUy5Pbtjio5pyq00'
download_from_url(CSV_GDRIVE_URL, CSV_FILENAME)

TEXT = data.Field(tokenize = 'spacy', batch_first = True, lower=True)  #from torchtext import data
LABEL = data.LabelField(sequential=False, dtype = torch.float)

train = data.TabularDataset(path=os.path.join('/content', CSV_FILENAME),
                            format='csv',
                            fields = [('Insult', LABEL), ('Comment', TEXT)],
                            skip_header=True)


print(vars(train[0]),vars(train[1]),vars(train[2]))

TEXT.build_vocab(train)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to manually download&upload the file as suggested by @knoop. As I provided in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61071096/4228275) to your question, you should not use the link with `open`. You should change to `uc?export=download` instead. In this way, the correct `CSV_GDRIVE_URL` should be:

```py
CSV_GDRIVE_URL = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1eWMjusU3H34m0uml5SdJvYX6gQuB8zta'
```

Then, if you `cat` it, you'll get:

```
,Insult,Date,Comment
11,0,20120530044519Z,"""Be careful,Jimbo.OG has a fork with your name on it."""
1478,0,,"""@dale0987654321 @\\'Micah Carter So you\\'re saying those claims are all false...?  I don\\'t know... just from my understanding these are in his book.... but I can be wrong... I\\'m just saying if they are true....should I just assume he\\'s racist?\\n\\nFrom \\'Dreams of My Father\\',""I CEASED TO ADVERISE MY MOTHER\\'S RACE AT THE AGE OF12 OR 13, when I began to suspect that by doing so I was ingratiating myself to whites""From Dreams of My Father, "" I FOUND A SOLACE IN NURSING A PERVASIVE SENSE OF GRIEVANCE AND ANIMOSITY AGAINST MY MOTHER\\'S RACE"".From \\'Dreams of my Father\\', ""The emotion between the races could never be pure..... the THE OTHER RACE (WHITE) WOULD ALWAYS REMAIN JUST THAT: MENACING, ALIEN AND APART""From Dreams Of My Father, ""never emulate white men and brown men whose fates didn\\'t speak to my own. IT WAS INTO MY FATHER\\'S IMAGE , THE BLACK MAN, THE SON OF AFRICA, THAT I\\'D PACKED ALL THE ATTRIBUTES I SOUGHT IN MYSELF.From Dreams Of My Father:""THAT HATE HADN\\'T GONE AWAY,"" he wrote, BLAMING WHITE PEOPLE,- SOME CRUEL, SOME IGNORANT, sometimes a single face, sometimes just a faceless image of a system claiming power over our lives."""""
1983,0,20120610152024Z,"""Only fucking with number 2... that's prolly the only pair i can pull off \xa0out these."""
3201,1,,"""S T F U and pay your dues"""
3549,0,20120530024115Z,"""Worry about your current opponent...."""
3402,1,20120618222736Z,"""And while you're at it, please prove how your ""point"" related to past draconian laws that banned inter-racial marriage?\xa0 That intent was to ""ban"" mixed races.\xa0 Just stop it please! You are insulting intelligence."""
2233,0,20120620034735Z,"""I'd rather have an old, straight white guy than the stupid fcking zebra we have now....everything he touches turns toshit............"""
3219,1,20120619020631Z,"""Only a black racists idiot would claim that the NAACP is not racist in todays world, especially since you're a member.\n\nAnd I don't give a 'bo' whether you take that personally or not."""
3148,0,,"""Fight for money !!! go ahead ,kill yourselfs, all for greed,common, take decision that is not in accordance with what the supreme court says, find some connection by the INEC ,and say to yourself ,HO IS MY TURN TO LOOT NOT YOURS,OR I KILL U.bounch of shameless idiots."""
386,0,,"""The cleverest comment that I have seen for a long time, I think that it was in the Mail\\n\\n \\n\\n\\'Arshavin is the worst Russian Sub since the Kursk"""""
```

And `TEXT.build_vocab(train)` will run successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Your script fetched the HTML file instead of the actual dataset. It is because the URL you used `'https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ctPKO-_sJbmc8RodpBZ5-3EyYBWlUy5Pbtjio5pyq00'` is not a direct URL to the csv file. It is rather in HTML format because the provided URL is of Google Sheets. To solve this, you can download the dataset to your computer and upload it to Colab.

This is the content of the data.csv that you fetched.

[image: Contents of data.csv]

Comment: knoop, thanks for your answer. I have uploaded the data from the local drive other than the from the g drive, it works. I have examined the loading results by using print(var()). Seems like it is what it should be. I think you gave the right solution. Thanks.